# geth: command not found (Ubuntu)

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, mist, private-key, bug

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed, and I just installed Mist. To my understanding, installing Mist should have installed Geth as well, but when I do the command

```
geth
```

in a terminal, I receive

```
geth: command not found
```

**Question:**

Is this supposed to happen? Am I doing it wrong?

---

**More context:**

I installed the **Mist-linux64-0-10-0.zip** found on https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases , then I extracted it in a folder, and then I run the

```
./mist
```

command, which opens up mist, and I downloaded the blockchain from there. So mist works as far as I can tell. However I was unable to import a private key for some odd reason because when I go to

- *File > Import accounts*

It is grayed out. I don't know if this is geth related, but I saw online tutorials that teach you how to import private keys with geth if you're having problems the other way. Though since I can't seem to get geth to work, I am at a standstill.

All help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Needs to b run from root folder. Try 'systemctl start geth' , 'geth attach' for mainnet.

Answer (score 0):

Mist distro does not include `geth` executable, but according to [README](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/df2b54d098e16c1e91a813fa1baf6fd6173b105b/README.md#config-folder), Mist downloads the latest `geth` version and stores in into its configuration folder.  For Linux it is `~/.config/Mist`, so look there.